# jQuery fade in a div function for a specific slide on canvas (using js)

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery fade in for a specific div function for a specific slide on canvas with a set time to .fadeIn().

Need div="fade" to appear once I arrive at the sixth slide in my canvas web app (based on reveal.js - http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/#/).

The jQuery function works perfectly when div="fade" is put within the first  area, but if it is placed within any other section), by then of course the page onLoad happened a long time previously (which is when div id="fade" is set to load the div per:

jQuery:

```
$(function(){  // $(document).ready shorthand
  $('#fade').fadeIn(2200);
});
```

HTML5 Section #6 (want div="fade" to work inside here):

```
...
</section>
<!-- end section 5 -->

<!-- begin section 6 -->
<section>
<div>
<p>
<a href="#">Interviewing a Co-founder<br>
<img src="img/misc/..." width="60" height="50" />
</a>
</p>
</div>

<div id="fade" style="display:none;">
<div id="browsers">
<p>
<a href="#" target="_blank">Fundraising<br />Campaign</a>
</p>
</div> <!-- END fundraising 'browsers' -->
</div> <!-- END fade jQuery --> 
</section>
<!-- end section 6 -->
```

...just as a side note, or for those who are unfamiliar with this canvas, each  +  + ... marks the next 'slide' when you arrow-over using the app... again, you can see example at: http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/#/.

I am happy to work with a fix using good old-fashioned js or jquery.

Comment: Is there any way you can bind to some event for the slide being changed to see what the current slide number is, and run the animation based on that?

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/) of reveal.js:

```
Reveal.addEventListener( 'slidechanged', function( event ) {
    // event.previousSlide, event.currentSlide, event.indexh, event.indexv
} );
```

So, you can call `fadeIn` like this:

```
Reveal.addEventListener( 'slidechanged', function( event ) {
    if(event.currentSlide==6){
        $('#fade').fadeIn(2200);
    }
} );
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked, however, for some reason I had to keep:

'<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){  // $(document).ready shorthand
  $('#fade').fadeIn(2200);
});
</script>​'

in the <head> of my html

and then pckill's code (thanks btw!), in the >body> (right before the closing </body> script):

'Reveal.addEventListener( 'slidechanged', function( event ) {
    if(event.currentSlide==6){
        $('#fade').fadeIn(2200);
    }
} );'

I tried other ways w/o luck, please share if you know why - otherwise, just use it like this - it works! ([http://kimerick.com/#/5])

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like,

```
Reveal.addEventListener( 'slidechanged', function( event ) {                
   if(event.indexh == 1){ //to get the slide number
     $('#fade').fadeIn(2200);
   }
});
```